# Drupal MySQL error after prefix change

Tags: database, drupal, prefix

I setup a drupal website, which first had a prefix but I dumped an old database export in the database that does not have a prefix. So I removed it from my settings.php, as per below:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'db_name_here',    //hidden
      'username' => 'username_here',   //hidden
      'password' => '*******',         //hidden
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',                  //prefix used to be here 'example_'
    ),
  ),
);
```

Problem however is that when I connect to the database, it still seems to look for the table with prefix. What did I do wrong?

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'db_name_here.example_semaphore' doesn't exist: SELECT expire, value FROM
{semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init )
in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/public_html/demo/site/includes/lock.inc).
```

Comment: Did you clear the caches?

Comment: Could you search for example_ in your files? I don't know if there is any caches, but cleaning them, restarting the services maybe helps.

Comment: Hi Clive en Lajos, cleared cache, restarted services and looked through all files for the prefix, but did not find anything and nothing of the above did solve the problem :(

Comment: Have you used Drush ? Look at the bottom of your settings.php file and see if there isn't any other $databases var redefined there.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Drupal with database prefix, all your database tables will also get that prefix so to remove prefix you need to rename all database tables.

Following script will help you to do this.

```
<?php
// current table prefix to be removed
$prefix = "drup_";
// echo generated statments rather then run them
$pretend = FALSE;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$table_list = db_query("SHOW TABLES");
$prefix = strtolower($prefix);
foreach ($table_list as $r) {
  $r = (array)$r;
  $table_old = strtolower(current($r));
  // check for $prefix on this table
  if(substr($table_old,0,strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
    $table_new = substr($table_old, strlen($prefix));
    // first drop $table_new incase it already exists
    $clean_sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$table_new}";
    // rename prefix table to standard/nonprefix name
    $rename_sql = "RENAME TABLE {$table_old} TO {$table_new}";
    if($pretend) {
      print $clean_sql."\n";
      print $rename_sql."\n";
    } else {
      if(!db_query($clean_sql)) {
        die("Aborting - $clean_sql \n");
      }
      if(!db_query($rename_sql)) {
        die("Aborting - $rename_sql \n");
      }
    }
  } else {
    print "$table_old skipped \n";
  }
}
print "\nDone \n\n";
?>
```